# Good HTML and CSS to use with <input type="radio">?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

What's the best way to use `<input type="radio">` in HTML?

I'm looking for HTML that's semantically good, whose formatting is configurable via CSS.

I want to be able to style/render it to look something like:

```
    Car: (o) Yes
         (X) No
         (o) Maybe

  Train: (o) Yes
         (o) No
         (X) Maybe

Address: [An input text box     ]
```

Thinking of the CSS, I think that I'd like the labels on the left (e.g. "Car" and "Bus") to be in some kind of `text-align: right` block?

I don't know about the radio buttons on the right: in some kind of `<span>` perhaps, with `"display: inline-block"`? Or `"white-space: pre"`?

What kind of block-level tags (e.g. `<p>` or `<div>`) and/or other tags (e.g. `<span>` or `<br/>`) would you recommend?

---

**Edit:**

How about the following.

HTML uses `<legend>`, like HTML is supposed to and as recommended in [the alistapart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms):

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Car</legend>
<label><input type="radio" name="car" value="yes"/> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="car" value="no"/> No</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="car" value="maybe"/> Maybe</label>
</fieldset>
```

To make it easer for Firefox to access/position the contents of the `<legend>`, place it within a `<span>`:

```
<fieldset>
<legend><span>Car</span></legend>
<label><input type="radio" name="car" value="yes"/> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="car" value="no"/> No</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="car" value="maybe"/> Maybe</label>
</fieldset>
```

Then, use the browser-specific CSS described in [Legends of Style Revised](http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/legends-of-style/) to position the contents of the span to left of the fieldset.

Does the CSS really have to be so complicated and browser-specific? What's the simplest CSS which ought theoretically to work, instead of the more-complicated CSS required to actually work with those imperfect browsers? If `<legend>` is hard to position then what's a good (semantic) alternative?

Comment: it's just tyo or what <input text="radio"> it should be <input type="radio">

Comment: @Salil: it looks like a *tyo* to me ;-)

Comment: i look at the title carefully and i get it's just typo.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use `<fieldset>`.

The difficulty with positioning a `<label>` in different browsers is described in the "[Legends of Style Revised](http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/legends-of-style/)" article; so instead of using a `<label>` and trying to position it, I might use a `<span class="label">` outside the `<fieldset>`.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I usually do with my radio buttons and checkboxes.  It allows the associated text to be clickable in most browsers without having to do any work, which makes the form a little easier to use. The CSS `cursor` change helps to alert the user to this feature.

CSS

```
label { cursor: pointer; }
```

HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="maybe"> Maybe</label>
```

Alternatively, use a `fieldset` legend for cars and a `ul` for the list of  radio buttons:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Cars</legend>
    <ul class="radio-list">
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="maybe"> Maybe</label></li>
    </ul>
<fieldset>
```

CSS

```
.radio-list li { list-style: none; }
```

Stylizing a `fieldset`/`legend` to be consistent across browsers isn't too difficult; however, it does require one IE conditional if you want a border around the `legend`.  The only extra HTML that is necessary is a wrapper `span` within the `legend`.

CSS

```
<style>
    fieldset {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        padding: 1.6em 10px 0px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    legend {
        position: absolute;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    legend span {
        position: absolute;
        top: -1.1em;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /* This isn't necessary, just here for list aesthetics */
    ul, li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
    legend {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><span>Did you enjoy your SO experience?</span></legend>
    <form>
        <ul>
            <li><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="maybe"> Maybe</label></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

That's about as simple as I can get it. [Live example](http://jsbin.com/uhuzi/3)

Comment: In the first example, how do you get the labels to arrange vertically to the right of the legend? In the second example, is having `<ul>` and `<li>`s a lot of extra display-related non-semantic markup?

Comment: @Chris: It's a list of radio buttons. It's *completely* semantic markup and entirely valid. What *isn't* valid is trying to turn it into a list by using CSS on the labels. Labels aren't block level elements by nature, use them accordingly.

Comment: @Chris: I added a live example. Depending on *precisely* how you want your form laid out this may work. Needing the lineup the way you have indicated would mean removing the border around a fieldset and floating the legend left while providing the ul with an additional margin to compensate.

Comment: @Chris: I updated that with a second form that styles it more like your original question.

Comment: It is more like original the question; except that (using IE8 and using Firefox) the `<legend>` is above as well as to the left of the radio buttons. I'd prefer it to be level with the corresponding button[s] on the right, in order to match other things on the form (e.g. where a label on the left is level with a corresponding `<input type="text">` on the right).

Comment: @Chris: That page is bare. By bare I mean no CSS reset or the like. Including something like [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org) would probably alleviate all or some of those issues.

Comment: @Josh I ammended my OP to reference an article which shows how to position a `<legend>`; but that CSS seems complicated to me, and browser-specific ... but using `<legend>` is probably the most semantically correct; so, what a dilemma.

Comment: @Chris: I included the blueprint styles, let me know if that fixes the rendering.

Comment: It doesn't fix it, in either browser. http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/legends-of-style/ suggests something more complicated.

Comment: @chrisw Adding `display:block` to `label`'s is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Justin Johnson I agree with adding `display:block` to `label`s is reasonable, is, but I don't know why you're suggesting it: doing that wouldn't help with getting the legend positioned to the left of the radio buttons.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been in response to JoshK's first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm.... `Car` and `Train` should definitely be `<label>`s. Check out this classic A List Apart article for a really nice example: [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms)

As for the radio button labels: Good question! I'd say `<label>` s again, but a `<span>` would do as well.

Comment: @Pekka: interesting, the article uses a `<label>` element for the radio options (yes/no), but a `<legend>` element for the caption.  I would definitely say `<label>` for the radio button labels, especially for accessibility (correctly using the `for` attribute).

Comment: alistapart is using `<fieldset>`, with `<legend>` (not `<label>`) for `Car` and `Train`.

Comment: @Andy I think using `label for` won't work for each individual radio button because they all have the same name. Still, `label` is probably the best choice here. As @Chris correctly notes, ALA are using a `fieldset` for the radio options. Not sure whether that makes 100% sense to me.

Comment: Unfortunately it's using `display:block` for the labels, so its markup ensures that the legend is above (not to the left of, which is what I want) all the radio buttons and their labels.

Comment: @ChrisW: `legend` is written on the `fieldset` border.

Comment: @Amadan - you're right: so it is. Is the display of that configurable, or, must I therefore want to use something other than `<legend>`?

Comment: @Pekka — the `for` attribute keys off the `id`, not the `name`.

Comment: A label can be associated with one, and only one input. You can't associate a label "Car" with the fields "Yes", "No" **and** "Maybe"

Comment: @Pekka: `label for` looks up `id`, having same `name` doesn't matter. `label` is made for labelling boxes - they are small and clickable only with difficulty, so `label` extends the targeting area.

Comment: @Pekka: the `for` is applicable to the `id` attribute, not the `name` attribute -- [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).  Also, ALA are wrapping the label element around the input element instead, which I thought had issues in IE but I could be wrong.  The `<label>` element's purpose is to associate with an `<input>` element for accessibility - clicking on the label will than perform an action on the associated input, either focusing it (text input/select) or checking it (checkbox/radio).

Comment: @Andy @Amadan ah, makes sense. Wasn't aware it was possible to target `id` s as well.

Comment: @David I see - that's why ALA are using the fieldset in their example. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Pekka — not *as well*. The for attribute does not target the name attribute, ever. Just the id attribute.

Comment: @David @Andy hah, I've been doing this wrong for years now! :) I stand corrected. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

css: (ugly class names need to be changed)

```
p.radio { height: 4em; }
label.top {
  display: block;
  width: 4em; /* or something else */
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}
```

html:

```
<p class="radio">
  <label class="top" for="car">Car:</label>
  <input type="radio" value="yes" name="car" id="car_y" />
  <label for="car_y">Yes</label><br />
  <input type="radio" value="no" name="car" id="car_n" />
  <label for="car_n">No</label><br />
  <input type="radio" value="maybe" name="car" id="car_m" />
  <label for="car_m">Maybe</label><br />
</p>
```

EDIT: didn't see the other answer. Using a fieldset instead of a paragraph and legend for the "top-level" label seems to be a good idea IMO.

EDIT2: according to comments, and I agree, using a list would be cleaner here. The new version would be :

css:

```
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
legend {
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 4em;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outer;
}
```

html:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Car:</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" value="yes" name="car" id="car_y" />
      <label for="car_y">Yes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" value="no" name="car" id="car_n" />
      <label for="car_n">No</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" value="maybe" name="car" id="car_m" />
      <label for="car_m">Maybe</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

That would be much more elegant. But even with `display:block` firefox doesn't seem to want to set the width of a `legend` element. Strange bug.

Comment: So you're getting the top-most legend to the left by doing `float: left`, instead of getting the radio buttons to the right using `display: inline-block`. Yea, that could be a good way to do it.

Comment: @Josh K - Why is it a list? Are `<input type="radio">` element usually supposed to be contained within list items?

Comment: There is no element with the id *car*, so the first label is not associated with any form controls.

Comment: @Chris: It doesn't need to be, but according to how you are presenting, it's a list of radio buttons.

Comment: @David Dorward - That's true. What would you do to correct that: replace it with a `<span>`?

Comment: legend, as per earlier answers

Comment: @David It's difficult to position a legend to the left of the radio buttons: see e.g. [Legends of Style Revised](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms).